# Coprime ideal from ring of integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

> Let $K$ be a number field. Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and let $C\in Cl_K$. Prove that exists $J\in C$ coprime to $I$.

I thought considering somehow the norm of $I+J$ and then to show it's $1$ which will imply that $I+J$ is the trivial ideal $\mathcal{O}_K$. How can I find such an ideal $J$ with $N(I+J)$?

Comment: Did you want to ask whether given an ideal $I$ and a class $C$ that there's an ideal in the class $C$ coprime to $I$?

Comment: But for that you take any ideal coprime to $I$ and it's in some class...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oops. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frak a$ be any ideal in the class $C^{-1}$. If $a$ is a nonzero element
of $\frak a$ then $a\frak a^{-1}$ is an ideal in the class $C$. So we need
to find such an $a$ with $a$ coprime to $I$.

Let $P_1,\ldots,P_m$ be the prime ideal factors of $I$. If
$a\in \frak a$ but $a\notin P_j\frak a$ then $a\frak a^{-1}$
will be coprime to $I$. So we need to prove that $\frak a$ is not
the union of the ideals $P_j\frak a$.

Comment: Why does the last claim holds?

Comment: That's what you need to find a suitable $a$.